# How to create Media video youtube entity programmatically?

Tags: 8, media

I have Youtube URL such as: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asddasOds32

I need to create Media video youtube entity programmatically.

Can I have some example code to solve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code example:

```
use Drupal\media\Entity\Media;

$media = Media::create([
  'bundle'      => 'my_youtube',
  'uid'         => 1,
  'name'        => 'my_video',
   'field_media_oembed_video' => [
    'value' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZ53oOOTsdc',
   ],
]);

$media->save();
```